# Get names of MultiIndex level 0 after using dropna()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a multiIndexed DataFrame. What I want to do is remove columns if any of the cell is NaN and then get the names of level 0 index.

```
data=
        A        B        C
      d   e    f   g    h   i
0     1   2    3   4   NaN NaN
1     1   2    3   4   NaN NaN
2     1   2    3   4   NaN NaN
3     1   2    3   4   NaN NaN
```

I used data.dropna(axis= 1, inplace= True) and got the following result.

```
        A        B  
      d   e    f   g
0     1   2    3   4
1     1   2    3   4
2     1   2    3   4
3     1   2    3   4
```

Now I used print(list(data.columns.levels[0])) but shows the following output.

```
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

How do I only get ['A', 'B']?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [remove the unused levels](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels.html) after dropna:

```
data.dropna(axis= 1, inplace= True)
data.columns= data.columns.remove_unused_levels()
```

---

```
print(data.columns.levels[0])
#returns Index(['A', 'B'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks. Few questions:
1> Won't dropna() remove the column C in the dataframe?
2> With `data.columns= data.columns.remove_unused_levels()`, are we replacing the columns in the dataframe?

Comment: When columns are mutiindexed. A slice of the dataframe doesn't remove the multiindex levels hence we drop the not used levels in the current slice and assign back as columns in the new dataframe